# Speed up the creation of a circular ROI on a 4K 25 fps video in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am working with a 2h-long 4K MP4 video shot at 25 fps. I am using openCV in python 3. From the video, I need to extract 3 circular ROIs.

Because of the large number of frames (212831), processing the whole video frame by frame with the code below takes over 24h on a 64 GB RAM workstation. Is there a way to speed up the processing or a workaround that does something slightly different to a similar effect?

Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import time

# name of source video and paths
video = 'C0023_2hanalysis'
input_vidpath = 'path_to_video/' + video + '.MP4'
output_vidpath = 'path_to_video/' + video + '-withROI.MP4'
codec = 'avc1'

# set ROI coordinates extrapolated from last video frame as well as fixed     parameters for analysis (radius)
x = 1188 # in pixels
y = 1204 # in pixels
radius = 75

# set parameters for output video as identical to input
fps = 25.0
scaling = 1.0 # output vs input video speed (?) 

## import video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_vidpath)
if cap.isOpened() == False:
    sys.exit('Video file cannot be read! Please check input_vidpath to ensure it is correctly pointing to the video file')

## Video writer class to output video
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*codec) # concatenate the 4 chars to a fourcc code, i.e. the 4-char name of the codec used to compress the frames
# adjust output frame size to scaling if any is applied
#(frame shape is given as height,width , so the output needs to be re-ordered to match VideoWriter arguments)
o_height = cap.read()[1].shape[0]
o_width = cap.read()[1].shape[1]
output_framesize = (int(o_width*scaling),int(o_height*scaling)) 
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename = output_vidpath, fourcc = 0x7634706d, fps = fps, frameSize = output_framesize, isColor = True)

## apply ROI frame by frame and thread them back into output video
start = time.time()
f = -1
last = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read() #'return' value (T/F) and frame

    this = cap.get(1) # get 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES'
    if ret == True:
        #frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = scaling, fy = scaling, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR) # no need to resize in this case

        # Apply mask to area of interest
        mask = np.zeros((o_height,o_width), np.uint8)
        mask = cv2.circle(mask,(x,y),radius,255,thickness=-1) #image, row and column coord of centre of circle, radius, color (black), thickness
        frame[mask ==  0] = 0

        out.write(frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
        if key == ord("q"):
            break

        f += 1
        if f%1000==0:
            print(f)


    if last == this:
        break

    last = this

## When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)

## End time and duration
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print("--- %s seconds ---" %duration)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common mistake. You shouldn't call `waitKey(1)` when you want to process the frames as fast possible. That function is basically add a short sleep after processing each frame, and that sleep time is much longer that processing time.

You just need to remove that, and still you can just kill the process if want to stop in the middle.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
import time

# name of source video and paths
video = 'C0023_2hanalysis'
input_vidpath = 'path_to_video/' + video + '.MP4'
output_vidpath = 'path_to_video/' + video + '-withROI.MP4'
codec = 'avc1'

# set ROI coordinates extrapolated from last video frame as well as fixed     parameters for analysis (radius)
x = 1188 # in pixels
y = 1204 # in pixels
radius = 75

# set parameters for output video as identical to input
fps = 25.0
scaling = 1.0 # output vs input video speed (?) 

## import video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_vidpath)
if cap.isOpened() == False:
    sys.exit('Video file cannot be read! Please check input_vidpath to ensure it is correctly pointing to the video file')

## Video writer class to output video
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*codec) # concatenate the 4 chars to a fourcc code, i.e. the 4-char name of the codec used to compress the frames
# adjust output frame size to scaling if any is applied
#(frame shape is given as height,width , so the output needs to be re-ordered to match VideoWriter arguments)
o_height = cap.read()[1].shape[0]
o_width = cap.read()[1].shape[1]
output_framesize = (int(o_width*scaling),int(o_height*scaling)) 
out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename = output_vidpath, fourcc = 0x7634706d, fps = fps, frameSize = output_framesize, isColor = True)

## apply ROI frame by frame and thread them back into output video
start = time.time()
f = -1
last = 0
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read() #'return' value (T/F) and frame

    this = cap.get(1) # get 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES'
    if ret == True:
        #frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = scaling, fy = scaling, interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR) # no need to resize in this case

        # Apply mask to area of interest
        mask = np.zeros((o_height,o_width), np.uint8)
        mask = cv2.circle(mask,(x,y),radius,255,thickness=-1) #image, row and column coord of centre of circle, radius, color (black), thickness
        frame[mask ==  0] = 0

        out.write(frame)

        f += 1
        if f%1000==0:
            print(f)


    if last == this:
        break

    last = this

## When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)

## End time and duration
end = time.time()
duration = end - start
print("--- %s seconds ---" %duration)
```

Comment: This reduced processing time to 13h 40min.